# Creating inf file for driver

Tags: kernel, driver, inf

I have an app which uses a kernel mode driver. I have the .sys file of this driver only and it's source code.

How can I create .inf file for driver also?

Comment: What kind of driver it is? Is it filter drivers, miniport driver or file system driver? Below link provide you how to create sample inf file. Based on this sample you can create inf file for your device

Comment: Sorry, but I could not find the below link.

Comment: Sorry seems my copy paste of link didn't worked :) Well link is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548081(v=vs.85).aspx